# WSO2 CEP 3.0 for Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra, wso2, complex-event-processing

I need to use WSO2 CEP 3.0 for a project but I do not have a clue about it. My idea is to use the CEP engine as triggers on a little Cassandra database that I have created , to edit one field when another one is changed.

I have read the official documentation, searched on the support forums (stackoverflow included), googled about it, but still I do not know what steps I have to follow.

I would appreciate if anyone could give some explanation or any documentation for doing this task.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CEP is a processing engine that processes events in real-time.. To process events, events needs to send to CEP in some manner. In your case if any change occur db, there should be some other client or external party need send events to CEP. There are several default adaptors available which receive events. see the links [1] & [2] for more info..

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/Input+Event+Adaptors

[2] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/08/writing-custom-event-adaptors-for-cep-3.0.0/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had already visited those links before. Anyway, i did not know that I had to have another 3rd party app for sending the database events to the CEP (in fact, I had to learn all by myself because my project tutor is not helping too much). I will investigate that that 3rd party client and if I don´t see any useful info soon, I will try with another technology apart of the WSO2 CEP.